# Accessing Postgres database on Vagrant box using GUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ssh, vagrant

I have installed PSequel and wish to use it to view my PG database in a GUI that is in my Vagrant VM for my Rails app.

I have configured it as in the image below but can;t get it to connect.

[image]

The errors PSequel is giving me are:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/neil/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
    config.vm.box = "precise64"

  # Set the hostname to the project here for easy identification
    config.vm.hostname = "ntsite"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Forward rails server port 3000
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Forward elasticsearch server port 9200
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9200, host: 9200

  # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.ssh.keep_alive = true

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.memory = 512
    vb.cpus = 1
  end

  # config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: ".git/"

  config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/vagrant/src", type: "rsync", mount_options: ["dmode=777","fmode=766"], rsync__auto: true, disabled: false

  # Required for NFS to work, pick any local IP
  # config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.50.50'

  # Use NFS for shared folders for better performance
  # config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/vagrant/src", nfs: true


  # Enable provisioning with Ansible, specifying the location of the playbook.
    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "devbox/vagrant.yml"
      # ansible.verbose = 'vv'
    end
end
```

The output of running `vagrant up`:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 3000 => 3000 (adapter 1)
    default: 9200 => 9200 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 5.0.16 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /Volumes/Storage1/Code/ntsite/src/ => /vagrant/src
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Volumes/Storage1/Code/ntsite
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Comment: Your vagrant box is probably not `localhost`. If the SSH port is forwarded to localhost, certainly to different port. How do you connect to vagrant?

Comment: I normally just navigate to the directory my vagrant file is in and run vagrant up followed by vagrant ssh and it logs me in.  I then access my rails app by going to localhost:3000 in my browser ?

Comment: Please post the output of the `vagrant up` command as well as the contents of your `Vagrantfile`

Comment: @BrianMorton I've added all that you requested to my original post. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tell Postgresql to listen to external addresses (link on how to do this [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/)).

Answer (score 0):

Use `vagrant ssh-config` to output the settings used to access the vagrant vm when you use `vagrant ssh` from the commandline.

If using PSequel, check that not getting stuck on RSA-fingerprint issues by out using the ssh config output from the above to connect from command line, so that you can respond YES if asked about fingerprint.

eg `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p <port number>`

Also check the port number output from `vagrant ssh-config`, it is likely not to be the normal `22`, if so, add that to the ssh section in Psequel config.